# XElement.Add(XElement) automatically adds namespace to child node?

Tags: vb.net, xml-namespaces, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am using XElement to manipulate my xml file: to find target node and then add child node to it. But now I have one problem. Let's say my xml file looks like this:

```
<Report xmlns="MY_NAMESPACE"
  <Width>100</Width>
  <Height>100</Height>
  <ReportItems>
    <ReportItem>
...
</Report>
```

And I want to add a new `<ReportItem>` to the `<ReportItems>` node using VB.NET. In this link [How to: Create a Document with Namespaces (LINQ to XML) (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387082.aspx) it says that in order to declare and use namespaces, it needs to Imports them at the beginning of a file(it is different from C# usage). So I do `Imports <xmlns="MY_NAMESPACE">`. Now I need to 1) find the `<ReportItems>` node at first, and 2) add my new node. In order to do the first step, I tried

```
Dim xmldoc = XDocument.Load(MY_XML_FILE_PATH)
Dim target = xmldoc.Root.Elements("{MY_NAMESPACE}" & "ReportItems").FirstOrDefault
```

And to do step 2), I did

```
Dim newNode As XElement = _
    <ReportItem/>
target.Add(newNode)
```

Now there is the problem: if I don't specify the `"{MY_NAMESPACE}"` when I query the Root element, I can't find `ReportItems` at all. It is because the string is actually used to implicitly construct a XName object (god knows why I can't assign the NS to XName object explicitly), and this object is used to search. If I don't give the curly brackets part, it will search within empty namespace, so it can't find the `<ReportItems>`node which is in MY_NAMESPACE. But if I give this curly brackets namespace, the final xml file will look like this:

```
<Report xmlns="MY_NAMESPACE"
  <Width>100</Width>
  <Height>100</Height>
  <ReportItems>
    <ReportItem>
    <ReportItem xmlns="MY_NAMESPACE">    
...
</Report>
```

The second `<ReportItem>` is the newly-added one, but sadly this is not a valid file (my parser is complaining in the further processing of xml file). So how can I make this new item look exactly like the existing one, without any namespace? This has been driving me crazy. I spent a whole day to figure out that I need to add the curly brackets so that it will find the target node (it doesn't work like what the link above says that it adds and searches the default NS automatically), but now it adds something unnecessary? It's gotta be kidding me!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and my solution was to omit the duplicate namespaces when saving the Xml:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
settings.NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates

Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)
    Dim xdoc As XDocument = WriteDocument()
    xdoc.Save(writer)
End Using
```

You can also call XDocument.Save with SaveOptions parameters which has OmitDuplicates as well.

Comment: The XDocument.CreateReader method also supports this feature. "xDocument.CreateReader(ReaderOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces)"